# SAS calculate through a subset of an array

Tags: sas

In my data step, I want to calculate some new variables based on the part of the variables I have.

My data looks like this:

```
         grade1  grade2  grade3  grade4  grade5  grade6
  Linda    68      70      85      78      90      55
   Tim     78      67      80      85      91      66
```

I want to create new columns say, new_grade1 new_grade2 where

```
     new_grade(i) = grade(i*3)
```

My code is like this:

```
     data want;
          set old;
          array new_grade[2] new_grade1 new_grade2;
          array grade[6] grade1-grade6;
          do i=1 to 2;
               new_grade(i)=grade(i*3);
          end;
       drop i;
     run;
```

This code does not work because grade1,2,4,5 are not used. Is there a way I can only use grade3 and grade6 rather assigning array grade1-6?

I want my output to be like this:

```
         grade1 grade2 grade3 grade4 grade5 grade6  new_grade1 new_grade2
  Linda    68    70      85     78    90      55        85          55
   Tim     78    67      80     85    91      66        80          66
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean "grade 1, 2, 4, 5 are not used"? What are you expecting for output?

Comment: Are you getting an error message in the log or is is just producing unexpected results?

Comment: indices 1,2,4,5 of grade are not used due to `(i*3)`

Comment: Why?  Do you not have the other GRADExx variables?  Adding them to the ARRAY statement does not cost anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the code you posted ? It works correctly (when you change the last `end;` to be the required `run;`)

Comment: you are right. it is a typo. it does run now. I actually have a much larger dataset. Seems like my problem is caused by the dataset, but not the code itself.